# What is the best way to remove punctuation marks, symbols, diacritics, special characters?

Tags: php, preg-replace, special-characters, clean-urls

I use these lines of code to remove all punctuation marks, symbols, etc as you can see them in the array,

```
$pattern_page = array("+",",",".","-","'","\"","&","!","?",":",";","#","~","=","/","$","£","^","(",")","_","<",">");

$pg_url = str_replace($pattern_page, ' ', strtolower($pg_url));
```

but I want to make it simpler as it looks silly to list all the stuff I want to remove in the array as there might be some other special characters I want to remove.

I thought of using the regular expression below,

```
$pg_url = preg_replace("/\W+/", " ", $pg_url);
```

but it doesn't remove under-score - `_`

What is the best way to remove all these stuff? Can regular expression do that?

Comment: You could remove everything but `[A-Za-z0-9]` ;-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Depending on how greedy you'd like to be, you could do something like:

```
$pg_url = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/", " ", $pg_url);
```

This will replace anything that isn't a letter, number or space.

Answer (score 13):

Use classes:

```
preg_replace('/[^[:alpha:]]/', '', $input);
```

Would remove anything that's not considered a "character" by the currently set locale. If it's punctuation, you seek to eliminate, the class would be `[:punct:]`.

`\W` means "any non-word character" and is the opposite of `\w` which **includes** underscores (`_`).